# which databases does web.py support?

Tags: python, web.py

I have searched in the web.py's doc. but I can't find which `databases` does the web.py support?

As I have known now, it support mysql, sqlite, postgres, does it support others?such like `mongodb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to web.py source file: https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/db.py, the built-in ORM supports below databases directly:

- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- SQLite
- Firebird
- MSSQL
- Oracle

of course you can use SQLAlchemy as ORM too: http://webpy.org/cookbook/sqlalchemy